# checking a vector for its availability (performance issue)

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I want to check a vector to see if it has at least one element. Which one is faster?

```
if (vec.size()) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
if (vec) {
  ...
}
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: [`vector::empty()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty).

Comment: Is "if(vec)" really working?!

Comment: The later won't compile, vector does not have implicit conversion to anything acceptable in boolean context. (@Kamouth: no, it isn't)

Comment: Any way of doing it is probably super-fast anyway. But `!std::vector::empty()` clearly shows your intent, and is therefore the best choice.

Comment: agreed and on some containers, empty() will actually be faster, and it's not uncommon to change the type of your container as the program evolves.

Comment: The second is much faster, since the compiler doesn't even have to generate any code; it just reports the error and stops. The first is better if you want the code to do anything useful, though. And `!vec.empty()` might be a bit faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use just `vector::empty`, since it is specialized to this particular task.

```
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  for (int i=1;i<=10;i++) myvector.push_back(i);

  while (!myvector.empty())
  {
     sum += myvector.back();
     myvector.pop_back();
  }
```